# python tkinter how to organize the rows and columns

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, grid

Hi I'm trying to build a user interface and having problem with column and row positions. What I expect to see is some distance between buttons and entry widgets since I left two empty column between them. So why are they standing just next to the entry widgets and changing the distances between entry areas? Could anyone give me some help about this?

Here is the code...

```
from Tkinter import*

HMCC=Tk()

HMCC.title(" GUI v1.0 ")
HMCC.geometry("500x300")

entry_1 = Entry(HMCC)
entry_2 = Entry(HMCC)
entry_3 = Entry(HMCC)
entry_4 = Entry(HMCC)
entry_5 = Entry(HMCC)
entry_6 = Entry(HMCC)
entry_7 = Entry(HMCC)
entry_8 = Entry(HMCC)

entry_1.grid(row=2,column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=3,column=1)
entry_3.grid(row=4,column=1)
entry_4.grid(row=5,column=1)
entry_5.grid(row=6,column=1)
entry_6.grid(row=7,column=1)
entry_7.grid(row=8,column=1)
entry_8.grid(row=9,column=1)

Channel_1 = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel 1 : ")
Channel_2 = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel 2 : ")
Channel_3 = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel 3 : ")
Channel_4 = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel 4 : ")
Channel_5 = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel 5 : ")
Channel_6 = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel 6 : ")
Channel_7 = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel 7 : ")
Channel_8 = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel 8 : ")

Channel_1.grid( row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E)    
Channel_2.grid( row = 3, column = 0, sticky = E)    
Channel_3.grid( row = 4, column = 0, sticky = E)
Channel_4.grid( row = 5, column = 0, sticky = E)    
Channel_5.grid( row = 6, column = 0, sticky = E)    
Channel_6.grid( row = 7, column = 0, sticky = E)    
Channel_7.grid( row = 8, column = 0, sticky = E)
Channel_8.grid( row = 9, column = 0, sticky = E)

#button1 = Button(text="   START   " , fg="red"  )
#button2 = Button(text=" PAUSE "     , fg="blue" )
#button3 = Button(text="    STOP    ", fg="green")
#button4 = Button(text="QUIT"        , fg="black",command=HMCC.quit) 

#button1.grid( row = 1, column = 3)
#button2.grid( row = 2, column = 3)
#button3.grid( row = 3, column = 3)
#button4.grid( row = 4, column = 3) 

HMCC.mainloop()
```

[Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UnFA.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The entry widgets start on row 0, the labels start on row 2. Why would you expect them to all line up when they start on different rows?

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing in column 2, then tkinter will ignore it.

In addition to the comment posted above which contains the answer to your question, you can clean up your code significantly by just using a loop:

```
num_rows = 8
entries = [None]*num_rows
channels = [None]*num_rows

for i in range(num_rows):
    channels[i] = Label(HMCC, text = "Channel {0} : ".format(i+1))
    channels[i].grid(row=i+2,column=0,sticky=E)
    entries[i] = Entry(HMCC)
    entries[i].grid(row=i+2, column=1)
```

Better yet, use list comprehension:

```
num_rows = 8

entries = [Entry(HMCC).grid(row=i+2, column=1) for i in range(num_rows)]
channels = [Label(HMCC, text = "Channel {0} : ".format(i)).grid(row=i+2,column=0,sticky=E) for i in range(num_rows)]
```

Comment: for a beginner, I think the loop is better than using a comprehension. In fact, I would argue it's better for advanced developers too in this specific context. It's easier to understand at a glance, and definitely easier to debug.

Comment: Agreed - I realize that with the list method you also don't get back a reference to the actual Entry and Label objects, since you grid them at the same time. So you'd be better off using two list comprehensions for each anyway.